# CMake basic project setup

Tags: c++, cmake, setup-project

I'm new to CMake and re-learning C++, so I hope these are appropriate questions. I have a project in directory /projects/A and some .h files in /projects/include/open-source-project-1 that the A project depends on.

```
Sample Hierarchy:
/projects
  /CMakeLists.txt
  /A
    /CMakeLists.txt
    /a.cpp
  /B
    /CMakeLists.txt
  /include
    /open-source-project-1
      /includeMe.h
    /open-source-project-2
```

1. Do I need to use a cmake include_directories() command? If so, in what CMakeLists.txt file do I need to put it in? (I've tried many variations)
2. Do I need a different cmake command?
3. If I put that in the top most level CMakeLists.txt, should that take care of all occurences of #include  in the .cpp files for the A project or B project?
4. Is this a typical setup for a c++ project? Does it seem logical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file is **not** needed unless all of the projects are directly inter-related somehow or have otherwise unresolvable dependencies. *Unrelated* projects should not include each other, **nor** do they need a parent list file.

1. If A and B are **separate** projects, `./A/CMakeLists.txt` and `./B/CMakeLists.txt` should contain at least this line:

   ```
   include_directories(../include)
   ```

   Otherwise, if A and B are *parts* of a larger single project, then it is appropriate to put these lines in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` files:

   ```
   include_directories(include)
   add_subdirectory(A)
   add_subdirectory(B)
   ```
2. Only for separate projects. One invocation of `cmake` will create **one** build tree. One project to a build tree is all you need.
3. No. Only if the top-level lists file contains an `add_subdirectory` directive will it affect the other list files.
4. No, this is atypical.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. Just as a side note, I was using #include <open-source-project-1/includeMe.h> in a.cpp while also using include_directories(../include/open-source-project-1), but was getting a No such file or directory error. Fixed by using include_directories(../include).